# Memory representation string in Little Endian and Big Endian

Tags: c, memory, endianness, cpu-architecture

```
char S[6] = "18243";
```

How is the following string represented in big vs. little endian systems?

Comment: [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) is irrelevant for arrays, arrays are always stored in the same order (first element first, last element last, with increasing addresses).

Answer (score 6):

The type `char` holds a single byte.  Because of that, there is no endianness involved with that type.

In your example you have an array.  Array elements are stored one after the other in memory.  So `S[0]` appears first, then `S[1]`, etc.:

```
  -----------------------------------
S | '1' | '8' | '2' | '4' | '3' | 0 |
  -----------------------------------
```

Comment: Would there still be no endianness where a `char` is greater than 8-bits?

Comment: @FiddlingBits Correct.  The number of bits in a byte doesn't matter when it comes to endianness of types.

Comment: `char` on a DSP with word-addressable memory can be 32 bits, and is usually called 4 bytes, not referred to as having huge bytes.  There's no way to separately access the bytes of each word (except with DMA, or with MMIO loads/stores), so byte-order within a `char` is still meaningless except for external hardware.  (ping @FiddlingBits, this is relevant to your question.)

Comment: @FiddlingBits While the C specification allows `char` types of differing bit-widths, it's still the smallest addressable unit on any target platform, and as such there's no endianness issues with a single `char`.

Answer (score 5):

Endianess only applies to numbers (larger than one byte).

A string is represented the same way no matter endianess: first letter at lowest significant address.

Comment: One might ask about other encodings like JIS, UTF-16, UTF-32 or other wide character types. I believe C supports wide characters (wchar_t).

Answer (score 2):

Lets say the <strike>compiler</strike>/<strike>linker</strike>/loader decided to put S at address 0x420000.

```
0x420000 '1'
0x420001 '8'
0x420002 '2'
0x420003 '4'
0x420004 '3'
0x420005 '\0'
```

Comment: Why strikethrough compiler and linker?

Comment: @FiddlingBits it mimics my thought process, and I thought a plain "loader" wouldn't be as informative.

Comment: Just trying to understand if it's relevant or not.

Comment: @FiddlingBits it's irrelevant, but informative :) like choosing `'\0'` or `0` is absolutely equal, so the choice is irrelevant